# Ng-Bootstrap active pills to add drop down not showing

Tags: css, angular, ng-bootstrap, nav-pills

I'm used my Angular-6 project for the [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) and i used [ngbootstrap-pills](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabset/examples), i tried to add active pills to drop down icon with removing button option, but its not working, anyone know how to do that correctly.

here with [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aticm5) code

this is my .css code

```
.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills.show> .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #262262;
}

a:after {
  content: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/60/60995.svg');
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -3px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

I tried to do like this image

[image: I tried to do like this image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution doesn't need .svg's to work.

[image]

```
::ng-deep .nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills.show> .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #262262;
  position: relative;
}

::ng-deep .nav-pills .nav-link.active:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;

  border-bottom: 6px solid #fff;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;

  display: block;
  left: 35%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aticm5-5nnhz3

Answer (score 1):

Try using `::ng-deep` selector to apply the styles. Otherwise the styles won't be applied to the library.

In your case it would be:

```
::ng-deep .nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills.show> .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #262262;
}

::ng-deep a:after {
  content: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/60/60995.svg');
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -3px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

You can also read about [Angular View encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation).

Comment: Your styles are applied now, before they did not work

Comment: I added your solution . color changed but not showing  arrow at the pills active

Answer (score 1):

**Hi I have modified some minor changes to your code please check out this StackBlitz Link**

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aticm5-2ghoez

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aticm5-4uexbg)

```
::ng-deep .nav-pills .nav-link.active:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 7px solid #262262;
  border-right: 13px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
}



::ng-deep .nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills.show> .nav-link  {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: #262262;
  padding: 8px 0;

}
```